# Assign attribute to object based on two fields of a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got an app with `illustrations` that `belong_to` `editions` that `belong_to` `novels`.  Currently `illustrations` do not `belong_to` `novels`, and I'd prefer if they didn't.  On the form I can pass the `edition_id` when creating the illustration but can't figure out a way to pass the `novel_id` since it's not an attribute of `illustration`.  I need to identify a unique `novel` `edition` pairing to create the illustration because many `editions` may have the name 1st, for instance, but different publication dates, etc....  I'm thinking I can make these a hash and then handle them in the controller.  I don't know how to do that though.  Is that the right approach?  How do you make a hash out of 2 fields in a form?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to do it from view?
If you need just pass to illustration novel_id, knowing edition_id:

```
@edition=Edition.find(params[:id])
novel_id=@edition.novel.id
```